# Some concession for first couple of questions posted by new user

Tags: discussion, new-users

[which is more important between connection and metric?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355374/which-is-more-important-between-connection-and-metric)

This question was posted by a new user before 40 minutes.

It was not a spam post.

It is not clearly mentioned what the question is.

Immediately, people here responded.

There are 3 down votes and 4 votes to close.

I do not see the necessity for such a quick negative response. We can wait for some time before giving  this negative feedback. If the user does not say anything with in some time, we can follow the usual procedure :)

> What does the community think about this procedure?

Comment: Thanks Martin for suggestion on tag :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're comparing to spam. The procedure for spam is flagging, and usually results in a deletion in less than 1 hour, and sometimes a few minutes.

Comment: A side remark is that new accounts are not always new users.

Comment: I meant to say quick negative reviews may be suitable for spam but for some question which is not spam, I think we should wait for some time..

Comment: I'm guessing you weren't around in the Usenet era.  On the Internet, eternal vigilance is the price of not being swamped by gibberish.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg  I understand to some extent what you mean :)

Comment: for the record, the question has now been deleted by the author, but it read: "In geometry, metric can be used to compute the curvature of tensor, but Levi civia connection is compatible with Riemmanian geometry."

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, the question is now deleted, For users below 10k, here is a [Internet Archive snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20200321153208/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355374/which-is-more-important-between-connection-and-metric).

Comment: These older discussions are also related to the issues concerning new users: [Should we exercise a bit more tolerance towards newcomers?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3518) and [“Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming.” — are we?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3713) (Although the issues discussed there are not the same as here.)

Answer (score 3):

There has long been two (probably more) factions within the MathOverflow community, of which an oversimplified description is this: some want to take the time to train new users, and some don't.

This user exhibits some enthusiasm and some vocabulary.  However, the examples posted by the user indicate to me that considerable effort will be needed to develop this user into a productive member of the forum.  I am willing to spend a little effort to indicate what is needed, but I can't spend enough effort to get this user to a level of participation that I think will be satisfactory.

Many of the people who vote to close I imagine belong a faction where maintaining quality content is more important than training new users.  This faction is important, but also influences how the forum as a whole is perceived.  I think your meta question touches on a deeper issue, that of what kind of set of services we want to provide as a community managing this forum.

Gerhard "Doesn't Have A Good Answer" Paseman, 2020.03.21.

Comment: Praphulla "I don't have a good response" Koushik :)