# Flood of Similar New User(s)

Tags: discussion, new-users, specific-user, multiple-accounts

The following thirteen(!) users:

[goingfullscheme](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330472/functors-reflecting-colimits)
[valua_aint_no_galois](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330404/when-are-valuative-criteria-useful)
[going-full-isomorphic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330390/schemes-admitting-a-cover-by-isomorphic-affine-opens)
[logicians_rule](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330342/connected-components-of-open-dense-subspace),
[martintzar](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330215/reading-off-the-geometric-properties-of-a-proper-scheme-from-its-affinization)
[royalroadtogeometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330207/are-geometric-conditions-open)
[bundlist](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330178/a-slightly-canonical-way-to-associate-a-scheme-to-a-noetherian-spectral-space)
[compactbut](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330168/compact-quasi-coherent-sheaves)
[faptoint](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330159/noetherian-stalks-imply-locally-noetherian)
[you_dont_mess_with_ron](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330000/finite-picard-group)
[ron_is_striking_back](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/329997/affine-open-with-irreducible-complement)
[Emmy_to_Noether](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330453/algebras-such-that-the-tensor-product-with-any-noetherian-algebra-is-noetherian)
[commutative_drinker](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330337/noetherian-and-finitely-generated-for-polynomial-algebras)

(and, I believe, a couple more besides) have the following characteristics in common:

- They've all joined in the past few days.
- Each has asked exactly one question
- Their questions are closely related to each other
- Their writing styles are very similar
- After posting their questions, they never return to engage with commenters, or to acknowledge answers

I think it is not too much of a leap to conjecture that these are all the same person.

As far as I know, there's no actual rule against having fifteen different identities (or for that matter, a hundred, as seems likely if this keeps up at this rate for a few more weeks), and no actual rule against asking questions and then systematically ignoring responses, but I still find it troubling in ways that might or might not be entirely rational on my part.  Do others share my discomfort?

---

Edit (YCor June 3, 2019): since the question was posted, here are a number of similar posts:

[user138661](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330690/grothendieck-topology-on-a-scheme-equivalent-to-the-circle) (account closed since then: not the original post name)
[m_for_motive](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330766/proper-variety-containing-no-affine-open-with-irreducible-complement)
[drama_dorama](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331666/the-underlying-space-of-an-affine-open-dense-subscheme)
[gentleman_gaga](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331914/does-the-structure-morphism-matter-in-gaga)
[motive_for_m](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332103/a-different-sort-of-affinization)
[livehard](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332120/equipotent-non-homeomorphic-schemes)
[user141225](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332839/checking-universal-closedness-on-immersions)
[PDShoot](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332949/scheme-locally-of-finite-type-over-the-affinization)
[Gimme An Answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332951/the-ring-of-global-sections-of-a-regular-scheme)
[La fille](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332969/non-empty-affine-open-with-an-irreducible-complement)
[Name](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333039/strongly-abnormal-schemes)
[Name](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333008/quasi-compact-morphisms-satisfying-the-valuative-criterion-of-properness) (not the same as previous one)

(there are a few more, for which the similarity is less obvious). In addition, this June 3, 4 of these posts have been bountied by other users: [cardinal](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332103/a-different-sort-of-affinization), [Cut the wood](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332969/non-empty-affine-open-with-an-irreducible-complement), kartop_man ([this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332949/scheme-locally-of-finite-type-over-the-affinization) and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332969/non-empty-affine-open-with-an-irreducible-complement), and now for the time being self-deleted: https://mathoverflow.net/users/141715/kartop-man).

---

**Edit:** I'll add more as I see them. Please note that these accounts have a tendency to comment on, edit, and answer each other's questions, or plan on offering each other bounties. The evidence I see points to one human in particular behind all this, and the situation is similar to that of another user and his ring of accounts a few years ago that some of you may recall, and who is now permanently banned from SE.

https://mathoverflow.net/users/141417/etalien 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141410/topo-mopo 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141546/naraka-path 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141523/preta-path 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141501/animal-path 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141500/human-path 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141498/asura-path 
 
New Asura Path, possibly temporary: https://mathoverflow.net/users/141752/asura-path?tab=profile 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141474/deva-path 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/140692/drama-dorama 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141703/curious-girl 
 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141716/phd 
 
New https://mathoverflow.net/users/141770/phd 
 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/141790/numberian (now 141790, 141792, 141793, 141794, 141795)

---

(YCor 2019/July/12) A last fact, of one higher level in misbehavior (if confirmed), is the use of an username that is a seemingly real name (Denis Chaperon de Lauzières), which has been a real user of MO (real accounts [here](https://mathoverflow.net/users/20038/denis-chaperon-de-lauzi%C3%A8res) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/users/57842/denis-chaperon-de-lauzi%C3%A8res)). Two suspicious posts under 1 user with this name were posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335925/what-can-one-say-about-covers-of-the-projective-line) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335953/a-scheme-not-locally-of-finite-type-over-any-affine-scheme) (user now removed and both question deleted by community), and a comment-like answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/335634/14094) (same name, other account - now converted to a comment).

Comment: I have over ten accounts on the Stack Exchange network myself. (This account is the one that I use most frequently as of late.) While I understand your concern, I think the content of the questions should be the issue, not the manner in which they were asked. Also, as user names can be changed, you might list user IDs instead. Gerhard "No, I'm The Other One" Paseman, 2019.05.01.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman :  There are some relevant differences, though.  For one thing, I'm not counting "accounts on the Stack Exchange network"; I'm counting accounts here on MO.  For another, you have multiple accounts under names that are recognizably yours, which seems a little less suspicious.  For another , your multiple accounts did not (I believe) all spring  forth full-blown nearly simultaneously.  And for yet another, you have no substantial history of hit-and-runs, where you ask a question, a commenter responds, and you're never heard from again.

Comment: I agree that there are differences. However, it is the behaviour that should be the focus. If there are thirteen hit and runs which result in thirteen average but worthy questions from which the community can benefit after improvement, that is better than one individual who gives thirteen poor questions and does not get the message on how to improve them for the forum.  Gerhard "How Good Are The Questions?" Paseman, 2019.05.01.

Comment: Gerhard:  Well, one issue you're overlooking is that I might not want to put much effort into this person's questions in the future, given the likelihood that my responses will be ignored.  If the username keeps changing, it's a little harder to identify the questions I prefer to skip by.

Comment: I have added ([meta-tag:new-users]) and ([meta-tag:multiple-accounts]), since they seem to be suitable tags for this question. I wasn't sure whether to add ([meta-tag:specific-user]) - probably not, since the question seems to be mostly about the general issue rather than about this particular user(s).

Comment: BTW the users you mention are unregistered user. Registration would decrease the likelihood that the asker looses access to his account. (Although it's not clear whether this is what happened here.) Past discussion related to registration: [Should MathOverflow require registration to ask a question?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3240)

Comment: Another explanation might be:  MO was mentioned by the instructor in some math class somewhere, and as a result 10 of the students decided to try it.

Comment: Having multiple accounts is not really prohibited. But it's a different case if it's used for malicious purpose, like trolling, avoiding ban, or even voting fraud. At this point, mods can check if they are related or not, and do something about it.

Comment: faptoint? Do you mean, fatpoint?

Comment: @GerryMyerson :  I did copy these by hand, so there could be typos, but it does seem to say faptoint.

Comment: OK. I asked because of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330156/non-empty-open-subscheme-reduced posted by https://mathoverflow.net/users/139941/fatpoint (so maybe fatpoint should be on your list?)

Comment: Possibly another to add to the list: https://mathoverflow.net/q/330539/30186

Comment: I would like to say in defense of these questions that several of them are interesting, such as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330337 , https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330178 , https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330168 , https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330159 , and all of them are at least  reasonable. This is different from other times when we've had a flood of what are clearly low level homework questions.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer :  I do not at all dispute that the questions are reasonable and in several cases interesting.  I even answered one of them!

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I don't think either of us are disputing each other; I just want to make sure people who are looking at this thread have a good understanding of the situation.

Comment: @Steven, I don't think I am overlooking the issue so much as waiting for you to clarify it. While it is good to engage with the original poster for clarification or increased understanding, it is not necessary. If someone comes along later and contributes well to the post, that works too. In either case, you are the judge of how worthy the post is of your time.  Gerhard "Have You Some More Concerns?" Paseman, 2019.05.02.

Comment: I wouldn't be very surprised if (at least some of) these are a computer program.

Comment: @MartinRubey I would love to see the code if all of these were written by a program. It got at least some of the semantics right.

Comment: More of the same:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330731/krull-dimension-of-the-ring-of-global-sections

Comment: Possibly https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330793/topological-spaces-with-possibly-non-uniquely-unique-scheme-structure.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, I hope that any instructor who prompted these will encourage the students to accept appropriate answers!

Comment: @NoahSchweber See also this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330775/a-scheme-whose-underlying-space-is-the-product-of-the-underlying-spaces-of-schem from a different account with (currently) the same user-name

Comment: @schematic_boi: I strongly believe that you are the one behind all these usernames.

Comment: @AlexM. OK, that is your right.

Comment: Steven: if you look at the comments on this deleted question https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4243/how-exactly-does-the-40-minute-limit-work you will see some user with certain opinions/interests adjacent to the present discussion mention, in a positive(!) way, the notion of having a bot that queues up a bunch of questions - could this account for the pattern here?

Comment: @YemonChoi I see via inbox that you (I think) have posted some replies to my comments there but unfortunately I can not read them because the question has been deleted. I did indeed mention setting up a bot because I do believe that some people can generate interesting questions at a rate faster than once per 40 minutes (you probably heard about some very smart people in your life and I have also seen some) and there is nothing wrong with that, as long as the bot obeys the rules. You seem to be insinuating something without making explicit accusations and I do not appreciate that.

Comment: I don't really understand your "positive(!) way" statement. If you could clarify what exactly is your problem with that, that might be helpful. I am not sure what opinions of mine are adjacent to whose, and my mathematical interests are not exactly rare or unusual.

Comment: @cardinal :  The fact that you've "generated an interesting question" is not sufficient reason to post to MathOverflow.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg your comment is slightly ambiguous. I never said I personally generate any interesting questions but I guess you mean in general. I agree with the general statement though I do not see how is it relevant here.

Comment: @cardinal This is probably OP, but I cannot imagine posting a question on MO without spending at least a day thinking about it to see if it is really nontrivial. And even so, I'd probably spend at least 20 minutes *writing* the question, to make sure I am satisfied with its formulation. In this light, you'll see why your "someone could produce a question every ten minutes" strikes me as ridiculous at best.

Comment: @DenisNardin this is backed up by [the FAQ](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question): 

_**Do your homework**_

_Before asking your question, try to solve it. Search Google, Wikipedia, and nLab, check any references you can think of, and try to figure the problem out yourself (maybe even sleep on it)._

Comment: On Deva Path's user page, I found this strange but seemingly relevant quote "The Six Paths of Pain are controlled by Nagato. The Six Paths of Pain do not answer, upvote, comment on each other's posts. The Six Paths of Pain award bounties on each other's posts." If the Six Paths of Pain refers to this group of users, this is according to what Todd said not completely true. This is apparently a reference to Naruto?

Comment: @WillSawin There are indeed six users with names of the form "... Path" (Human Path, etc.), all with the same description. I don't think awarding bounties on each others' posts is against the rules, but it is skirting the boundary (and jumping right past it if they use it to artificially decrease the costs of the bounties).

Comment: Adding this comment to insure that @ToddTrimble sees the two preceding comments.

Comment: Thanks to @WillSawin and Steven. I had to look up Naruto/Nagato, but FWIW, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83s%C4%81ra_(Buddhism)#Realms_of_rebirth

Comment: @StevenLandsburg What I find vexing is that to my non-AG eye, some of these questions look reasonable; but I really dislike the disingenuous behaviour of different user accounts interacting as if they are different people, even if this does not involve voting. I also find the creation of "one-shot" or "burner" unregistered accounts solely for the purpose of a high-volume of questions verging on obnoxious spamming

Comment: @YemonChoi :  Agreed on all counts.

Comment: @YemonChoi "I also find the creation of "one-shot" or "burner" unregistered accounts solely for the purpose of a high-volume of questions verging on obnoxious spamming": if you are referring to the limit on the number of questions a person can pose in a given time frame (one question in 40 minutes, I think), then that limit is enforced on the level of IP address (can the more enlightened confirm this?). So merely creating many unregistered (or registered) accounts will not allow you to ask questions at a faster pace than you could using a single account.

Comment: @YemonChoi In fact, if your sole purpose is to ask as many questions as possible, the best strategy would be to get your account 125 reputation points, then there is no limit; it is definitely not to create many unregistered accounts. Given this information, I can not understand the point of a part of your comment, I hope you can clarify.

Comment: @AsuraPath if not for this reason, then why create so many accounts?

Comment: @WillSawin I don't know, I guess everyone has their own reasons. I am personally just annoyed at the fact that a user can only have 3 bounties at any given point of time.

Comment: I am not sure why did you add drama_dorama. If you do have some reason, why did not you add https://mathoverflow.net/users/108486/bonbon?

Comment: Because that account doesn't fit the pattern we're seeing. I don't see why it should make any difference to you, if you claim you have nothing to do with these other accounts.

Comment: @DenisNardin by the way, please avoid making unfair accusations (I think the one you have made was unfair, see the previous comment). I want all discussions on MO to be civil, honestly. But since we have started this already, it is suspicious that you make unfair accusations against people with a different opinion.

Comment: Another one: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/141826/phd .  This one got a 100 point association bonus (16 mins ago?) but only has one account (MathOverflow).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche That was (at least) the third incarnation of "phd". It has since been (self-?)deleted, and then very briefly (a few minutes?) we had phd number 4+, (user141832) again arriving with an association bonus, but apparently deleting themselves after posting a few comments.

Comment: A veritable meteor shower of incarnations of "phd" this morning. Another one (user141854) shone for a very few minutes and burnt.

Comment: Hi: https://mathoverflow.net/users/141869/phd

Comment: @ToddTrimble:  yes---and as I'm sure you've noticed, he's arrived with an association bonus.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Yeah. I've now got some Community Management looking at the case, and we're pretty much in agreement with what's going on. Meanwhile, a very large number of accounts have been deleted.

Comment: @ToddTrimble:  once again, I'm very glad you're on this.

Comment: A brand new Asura Path: https://mathoverflow.net/users/142104/asura-path .

Comment: @Emil :  gone in under 16 minutes, I'm very glad to see.

Comment: @GetOffTheInternet user130022 doesn't quite "smell the same" to me but I could be mistaken

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334638/do-negative-indecomposable-bundles-on-curves-have-sections/334641#334641 concerns me. I answered the question because it seems legitimate, but it’s getting downvoted as if the person who asked the question is the same as the one who is making all the accounts. This isn’t good because it can scare legitimate new users.

Comment: @prf I have not owned a Mathoverflow account for a long time. A student of mine, whose account I am borrowing, for this once, brought this situation to my attention, and after some thought I believe it may be proper to point out to you a few aspects that I'm afraid you may be overlooking along the way. I will do so myself, in a way that I hope you'll read as friendly and benevolent, since it is.
According to your personal CV, assuming your identity has been correctly singled out, you seem to be a bright young student, eager to dive into advanced material and keen on teaching it to himself.

Comment: While this is admirable and potentially fruitful, provided your eagerness is harnessed the right way and accompanied by humility and patience, with the aim of not burning crucial steps in your learning process, you seem to have yet to fully appreciate how inappropriate your behavior has been so far, and that this may reflect badly on you in your nearest future. It seems you’ll be soon starting your freshman year at Harvard.

Comment: Let me point out that the disrespectful conduct you’ve been showing, does not match the one that would be expected from a person that is soon due to become part of a school that, among others, values character and moral fiber, and the capacity to bring to the table a positive drive for change.
It happened in the past that your future school rescinded admission offers due to unbecoming conduct, and very recently so. Why would a bright young man spend his time in this fashion, and why so persistently and unapologetically,

Comment: at the potential cost of jeopardizing his immediate future, is something I’m having a very hard time understanding.
Everybody makes mistakes: what’s important is to draw a lesson from them and turn them into, precisely, “a positive drive for change”.
I’m hoping you’ll take the following suggestion in a constructive way, and act on it, after taking some time for yourself to reach this conclusion on your own: leave a short message to the Mathoverflow community, down here, apologizing for causing so much confusion, and unnecessarily wasting a number of people’s time.

Comment: Then take a few months off from Mathoverflow. Do enjoy learning, in the more traditional “books and exercises” fashion. I wish for you to get to see by yourself how much this will pay.

Comment: regarding previous impersonation cases on SE network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279109

Comment: As to @YCor's recent edit -- googling and searching on zbMATH, I cannot find evidence that there is a mathematician named Denis Chaperon de Lauzières at all.

Comment: Regarding the new edit by @YCor and the mention of  Denis Chaperon de Lauzières, the unregistered accounts go back at least as far as 2011, which makes me uncertain that this is *directly* related to the current state of affairs. (You can find on tea a request to merge four unregistered accounts, one of which became the one linked in the edit.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila In a comment here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/63433/61785 Kevin Buzzard hints that Denis Chaperon de Lauzières might actually be called Emmanuel. There is a certain Emmanuel who wrote a blog post saying MathOverflow was silly and he would only contribute to it under a pseudonym.

Comment: @RobertFurber: And following the discussion here, it seems to me that this might not be the same person who created all those other accounts. Not to mention that all the accounts of "Denis" were always using the same name (and supposedly the same email, judging by the consistent Gravatar across the accounts).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I should probably have addressed my comment at Stefan Kohl, I was trying to affirm the idea that the original Denis was not related to the current user creating and deleting loads of pseudonymous accounts

Comment: Paging @StefanKohl :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks, this seems quite convincing that the name Denis CdL was a pseudonym. However it seems clear to me from his mathematical background that he's distinct from the recent multi-account user.

Comment: It seems the flood has abated...?

Answer (score 33):

With regard to Gerhard's response -- which I agree with -- I see a number of things problematic in some of the behavior taking place in the present circumstances.

I have no doubt that behind these numerous accounts is only a very small group of humans, and there's a very good chance it's just one. In other words, I am finding very clear evidence, using the moderator tools available to me, of sockpuppetry taking place. As you all know, sockpuppet upvoting is a significant violation of site (and SE) policy, but sockpuppetry is obnoxious for other reasons as well. In the present case, there have been numerous instances of the sockpuppets' answering each other's questions, editing each other's posts, and leaving comments on each other's posts. Even in cases where no sockpuppet upvoting is taking place, an appearance is trying to be created of great community activity and interest surrounding the posts in question. This type of attention-drawing is based on deceit, is thoroughly obnoxious, and is inherently problematic.

I think the behavior promised in this user profile https://mathoverflow.net/users/141500/human-path?tab=profile also qualifies as problematic:

> The Six Paths of Pain are controlled by Nagato. The Six Paths of Pain do not answer, upvote, comment on each other's posts. The Six Paths of Pain award bounties on each other's posts.

Judging from this post, it seems that Community Management agrees this behavior is not cool: [Who or what is this SO user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/who-or-what-is-this-so-user)

Still other problematic aspects include opening new accounts in response to other accounts being closed. In one case relevant here, an account named "mika" was (re)created after a same-named account was deleted, with the user openly saying so. Deletion can mean one of several things. One is that Community Management or site moderators have decided that the user is no longer welcome, in which case the user opening a new account is explicitly in violation of community moderation. Another is that the user is self-deleting the account voluntarily. But in this case as well, coming back again in a new form flouts the norms of this site, especially by enabling the user thereby to evade community moderation and policing. This is akin to question repetition, as when a user deletes his post and then asks again.

Still another problem -- more of a judgment call but nonetheless real -- is trollish behavior (sealioning, etc.). In my opinion, and in the opinion of other community members, there have been a few instances of that in the current circumstances, both at meta and at main.

In such cases, when the behavior becomes problematic and repeatedly so, we may have to clamp down a little harder. (Many of you will remember one or a very small band of users engaged in shenanigans a few years ago, with the main perpetrator now permanently banned from SE.) I don't have a problem per se with a user controlling a number of accounts -- as long as site policies and guidelines are not being flouted and deceit is not taking place. Otherwise I have a big problem with that.

---

I guess I'll begin documenting here suspicious events as I see them. For those users who seem puzzled about my linking certain posts on MO Main to this discussion, I repeat: forensic analysis strongly suggests to me that all of the many accounts listed above are associated with each other, and I think the community should be aware of events that are occurring within this circle.

For those with 10k+ reputation: the (unregistered) user "Curious girl" asks a spam question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333692/big-topos-guys-why which makes a crude joke about genital size.

User "cardinal" https://mathoverflow.net/users/74900/cardinal has the following recent reputation events https://mathoverflow.net/users/74900/cardinal?tab=reputation: yesterday there are 5 upvotes in the same minute 20:14, and 4 upvotes in the same minute 16:26. Today (June 11) there is a slew of upvotes all within a short span of time.

A number of accounts in this circle that are offering bounties follow a characteristic pattern where coincident with offering bounties, the account is scheduled for deletion. This will continue until past the time of deletion, and then the deletion will be rescinded.

A new version of Asura Path became a member today https://mathoverflow.net/users/141752/asura-path?tab=profile, after a same-named account was self-deleted. This self-deletion plus resurrection may be an attempt to circumvent ordinary moderation. Here is a list of posts by the old Asura Path: https://mathoverflow.net/admin/posts-by-deleted-user/141498

Comment: Thank you for being on top of this.

Comment: Seconded. Thank you not just for acting, but for posting this answer to clarify for those who might not have seen the recent activity

Comment: If I understand correctly, these are all unregistered accounts. These can't vote.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's a mix of registered and unregistered. Moreover, unregistered accounts can engage in shenanigans, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @ToddTrimble You should probably blockquote the profile text as it could change at any time (or the user might get deleted)

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: after visiting your link to the meta stackexchange, I only see two potential issues here. First is the system adding 50 reputation points to any bounty automatically (thus you can generate rep from nothing, but posting a bounty and giving an answer from another account). Second you can use this to avoid the reputation cap of max 200 points per day. The first point appears to be moot at this moment (i.e. 50 points are no longer being added). The second point is potentially relevant but none of the "... Path" accounts are using the bounties to transfer the reputation to any other accounts.

Comment: So I think the community management actually reviewed a case different from the one you are considering and the promised behaviour is cool.

Comment: I want to publicly voice my support for a policy of forcibly deleting these accounts as they arise, if the moderators find that action warranted.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Thanks for your support. Such an option is on the table.

Comment: [One of the users mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/users/141770/phd) has recently posted a 100 rep bounty on a question and I'm confused as to how they've got the reputation for that. According to their profile it comes from the association bonus, but there are no signs of their activity on other SE sites either.

Comment: @Wojowu This mystery is explained in the comment thread of https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4261 . The SE software actively assists abusers by making it possible to hide communities from your profile.

Comment: I find it enormously funny that the now deleted account of **user141498**, which is one of the accounts involved in this scheme, joins the conversation and shares some common sense wisdom on the subject with us.

Comment: @ToddTrimble You are probably aware of it, but I will explicitly mention that the link you've included - https://mathoverflow.net/admin/posts-by-deleted-user/141498 - is not visible by regular (non-diamond) users. Regular users can get list of posts from a deleted users using SEDE, as [discussed before on this meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3748), this does not include deleted posts. There are some stats about deleted users that might be interesting in connection with this, I have [mentioned some of them in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=query&room=94798).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/users/142965/gentbent appears to have acquired an association bonus by responding to trivial questions from https://augur.stackexchange.com/users/1822/maoboa on the Augur stackexchange, getting one upvote each time.

Comment: @RobertFurber yes, and also on a bunch of other sites, making them look reasonably engaged.

Comment: In a comment to the question below an unregistered user (?) puts a link to a page where someone explicitly named is accused to be below all this attacks. I am not sure if it is not part of the "conspiracy"... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335983/bounding-degree-of-closed-points-on-an-affine-scheme-of-finite-type-over-a-field

Comment: @Xarles Before that user was deleted, it was possible to see that that comment was posted by an alias of "Asura Path" (who had mysteriously acquired an association bonus without any posts), so we can't take what that site says at face value, since it seems to have been posted by the same person who is creating all these accounts.

Comment: @RobertFurber That it was my guess: it seems that whoever is doing all these posts is trying to accuse another one and even to damage his image.

Comment: @Xarles yes, it could be some kind of character assassination.

Comment: @RobertFurber The current profile of https://math.stackexchange.com/users/684254/asura-path looks odd, in the sense of linking to the site mentioned by Xarles while using a username that is apparently associated with this individual

Comment: To update my last comment, someone contacted me who could corroborate the identity on the curious website with the sockpuppet accounts, since they recalled the original name of user Cardinal was indeed this person's name, and some other interactions with third parties who used the given name.

Comment: @GetOffTheInternet seems like Lee Pak decided to delete their question...

Comment: @GetOffTheInternet One likely scenario is that the 'real' Aknazar, having been outed, claims that someone he knows has hacked his account and is maliciously using it to frame him. Then the same Aknazar creates this entity who has it in for him, thereby justifying the claim.

Comment: So far I don't think the last two meet the threshold.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that I can give a partial answer to your question. Looking at some of the profiles that you have listed, they seem to be all **unregistered** users. I used to do something similar (but with only 4-5 names) in 2012, at my beginnings on MO: not in bad faith, but because I was viewing my asking questions on MO as only a temporary thing. Plus, I was relying on the cookies mechanism to remember me between browsing sessions. Alas, somehow those cookies used to disappear after some time, which forced me to create a new unregistered name every such time. When I decided that MO is a useful community where I'd like to stay, I merged all of my unregistered usernames into the current, definitive one.

The solution to your question would be to tell this person in a comment to do the same: register and then ask the SE staff to merge all these usernames into a single account.

The longer-term solution [has been previously discussed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3240), but has been decided against: that unregistered questions should no longer be allowed, following the example of Math.SE. (Back then the issue was settled in the negative based on the consideration of solely the quality of the questions.)

Comment: Alex, that was prior to the merge into the SE network. This made merging unregistered accounts a bit slower, a bit more cumbersome, and out of the hands of local moderators.

Comment: You are right that when I posted [the question about registering](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3240/should-mathoverflow-require-registration-to-ask-a-question) I should have stressed this aspect too - if a question is posted by an unregistered user and they lose the account, it makes more difficult for them to follow the question, add comments, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Do(es)n’t said user(s) simply exploit the loophole once [detected](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1677) by @MattF. (newly created accounts can spend the association bonus on bounties), and wouldn’t that part be solved by following his then-suggestion (make the “set bounties” privilege higher than 101)?

Comment: The new incarnation of Asura Path got an association bonus both here (which they spent almost immediately on a bounty) and on math.stackexchange, although I can't see why they qualified on either site.

Comment: Also the second incarnation of “phd” got an association bonus and spent it almost immediately on a bounty, despite apparently being a member of no other SE site to qualify for the bonus.

Comment: It's a bit more difficult how much reputation a *deleted* user earned on MO - that could be used as an estimate whether some of the reputation came from association bonus. I have [tried to created some SEDE queries](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/94798/2019/6/12). For some users we'll have to wait for the next database update - for two users (138661 and 140765 - I saw that they earned enough reputation on MO.

Comment: As transpired on https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4261 , it is in fact possible to hide SE communities from someone’s profile. As far as can see, this misfeature is just a recipe for abuse.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is reasonable to be concerned, if only for the fact that we do not know what the ramifications of this behaviour are.

However, I think it is better to describe the behaviour and call out what might be problematic about the behaviour.  Right now, it seems we are getting OK to good quality material for the forum, and we have the ability to improve upon and respond to this material.  There is no suggestion of copyright, homework or exam flaunting, or other misbehaviour.

Bringing the situation to the attention of the community is good, but I don't see the quality or quantity a reason for concern.

Gerhard "Having One Name Is Boring" Paseman, 2019.05.02.

Comment: Gerhard, you have so many middle names, that it would take a small book to write them all. Asaf "This is not my real middle name" Karagila, date of comment is written after my name is written again by the system.

Comment: I look forward to the publication of The Many Middle Names of Gerhard "Whose Idea Was This, Anyway?" Paseman.

Comment: Volume II-M is available here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/3402/gerhard-paseman?tab=activity . Gerhard "Nine Other Volumes In Preparation" Paseman, 2019.05.03.

Comment: How about the following: Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong Gerhard "Recursion never goes wrong

Comment: Q: “What does the B. stand for in ‘Benoît B. Mandelbrot’?” — A: “Benoît B. Mandelbrot” 